# Does redistimeseries and the go client work with redis cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redistimeseries

I am trying out redistimeseries module with redis cluster and it's go and node clients. Is that supported ?

Comment: What do you by "is that supported"? Did you try this clients https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries-go

Comment: So redisTimeseries internally uses redigo to create redis client which doesn't seem to support redis cluster : https://github.com/gomodule/redigo/issues/352